# QString splitting multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, qt, split, qstring

I'm having trouble splitting a QString properly. Unless I'm mistaken, for multiple delimiters I need a regex, and I can't seem to figure out an expression as I'm quite new to them.

the string is text input from a file:

**f 523/845/1 524/846/2 562/847/3 564/848/4**

I need each number seperately to put into an array.

Some codes....

```
QStringList x;
QString line = in.readLine();
        while (!line.isNull()) {
            QRegExp sep("\\s*/*");

            x =  line.split(sep);
```

Any pointers?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your regular expression like this:

`QRegExp sep("(\\s+|/)");`

then `x` will have every number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried "||". Regex is powerful but oh so frustrating. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I found it quite useful to try out RegEx's interactively. Nowadays there are a lot of online tools even, for example: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

You can put your search text there and play with the RegEx to see what is matched when.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the strtok function, which split a QString with one or more different tokens.

It would be like this:

```
    QString a = "f 523/845/1 524/846/2 562/847/3 564/848/4";
    QByteArray ba = a.toLocal8Bit();
    char *myString = ba.data();
    char *p = strtok(myString, " /");

    while (p) {
        qDebug() << "p : " << p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " /");
    }
```

You can set as many tokens as you need. For further info visit the cplusplus page of this particular function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Regards!.